# activiti 6.0 and ldap integration

Tags: java, ldap, activiti, bpmn, spring-ldap

Looking at the activiti user doc https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#chapter_ldap,

I copied the activiti-ldap jar file from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-ldap/6.0.0) to

> webapps/activiti-app/WEB-INF/lib/activiti-ldap-6.0.0.jar

following error when I start the tomcat

```
    07:05:49,238 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [activiti-custom-context.xml]
07:05:49,331 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Overriding bean definition for bean 'processEngineConfiguration' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=activitiEngineConfiguration; factoryMethodName=processEngineConfiguration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/activiti/rest/conf/ActivitiEngineConfiguration.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [activiti-custom-context.xml]]
07:05:49,497 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [activiti-custom-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'configurators' of bean class [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]: Bean property 'configurators' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Jul 22, 2017 7:05:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [activiti-custom-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'configurators' of bean class [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]: Bean property 'configurators' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:154)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
  at org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:45)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'configurators' of bean class [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]: Bean property 'configurators' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:231)
  at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
  at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
  at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
  at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
  ... 24 more
```

Here is my custom config file

/webapps/activiti-rest/WEB-INF/classes/activiti-custom-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="configurators">
          <list>
              <bean class="org.activiti.ldap.LDAPConfigurator">

                <!-- Server connection params -->
                <property name="server" value="ldap://corp.abc.ad" />
                <property name="port" value="3268" />
                <property name="user" value="uid=Ad_user,ou=Service Accounts" />
                <property name="password" value="Pa55w0rd" />

                <!-- Query params -->
                <property name="baseDn" value="" />
                <property name="queryUserByUserId" value="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0}))" />
                <property name="queryUserByFullNameLike" value="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(|({0}=*{1}*)({2}=*{3}*)))" />
                <property name="queryGroupsForUser" value="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))" />

                <!-- Attribute config -->
                <property name="userIdAttribute" value="uid" />
                <property name="userFirstNameAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="userLastNameAttribute" value="sn" />

                <property name="groupIdAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="groupNameAttribute" value="cn" />

              </bean>
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

According to the Activi document, do I need to add the dependency as well in some Pom.xml ? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use spring class *PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer* instead of one of native ProcessEngineConfiguration classes provided by activity.

Please take a look at section "3.2. ProcessEngineConfiguration bean" in activity user guide.